# Aumentar la duración de la session en PHP

Tags: php, session, nginx

Tengo una página de inicio donde el usuario es redirigido si entra desde otra url de mi web. Como puedo aumentar la duración de la sesión, estoy utilizando un servidor VPS con Nginx. Este es el código que estoy utilizando sin éxito, la redirección se sigue produciendo al poco tiempo.

index.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);
    session_set_cookie_params(604800);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['hola'] = true;
?>
```

pag1, pag2, pag3...

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);
    session_set_cookie_params(604800);
    session_start();
    if(!$_SESSION['hola']){
        header("location:/index.php");
        die;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cambia el valor directamente en tu PHP.INI que tengas.  Para localizarlo haz un phpinfo().

Comment: @masterguru eso acabo de hacer, una pregunta. ya puedo quitar el ini_set en cada pagina, verdad? Y es mejor cambiar tambien session.cookie_lifetime en PHP.INI?

Comment: Si, el ini_set no siempre funciona (depende de varios factores). En cuando a lo del cookie_lifetime no lo se realmente... pruébalo sin cambiarlo y si ves que sigue cortándote la sesión entonces cambialo también.